# Tag based policies for EventBridge PutEvents

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

Is it possible to configure tag-based policies for the EventBridge PutEvents action?

My hope was that, based on tags in an IAM role, I could control which roles have access to PutEvents on specific event buses. I have attempted to do this with the following resource policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "allow_tags_to_put_events",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": "events:PutEvents",
    "Resource": "<event-bus-arn>",
    "Condition": {
      "StringEquals": {
        "aws:RequestTag/stage": "test"
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

This would allow any IAM role tagged with `stage=test` to be able to PutEvents. But this doesn't appear to be working. Reading this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazoneventbridge.html suggests that maybe `PutEvents` doesn't support the `aws:RequestTag` condition, but SOME of the actions do, which seems extremely odd to me.

Answer (score 1):

> which seems extremely odd to me.

Its not odd. Its rather common that some condition keys  apply to only specific actions, and not others.

So you already answered your own question. `PutEvents` action supports only few keys, none of which is `aws:RequestTag`:

- events:detail-type
- events:source
- events:eventBusInvocation
- aws:SourceArn
- aws:SourceAccount

Comment: I guess I considered it odd because it seems like the action where tag-based access would be most useful. EventBridge supports some request tag access, but not on the action that seems most useful. That is what I found odd, and wondered if it was a mistake. I guess not.

Comment: @JonNichols I understand. You have to get used to it. AWS very inconsistent, especially in IAM rules.